# Why would a user downvote an obvious tag synonym?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, down-votes

I recently re-tagged a question with the [grades](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grades) tag. I then looked at the synonyms and there is the [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) tag. I can't vote it as a synonym because my rep on either of these is probably 0. But there is a down-vote on the synonym suggestion, see:

https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/grades/synonyms

What are the possible reasons for this? Isn't it the consensus to try to clean up these tags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presumably the user who downvoted believes the distinction between grades (the quantitative measure assigned to a piece of work) and grading (the act of assigning a grade) is worth preserving.

For example, a question on how grades affect graduate admissions would be about [grades](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grades) but not [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading).

Comment: If that's the intended distinction, then perhaps the tags should be renamed to clarify the intent (e.g. renaming [grading] to [grading-process] or similar; I'm not sure what [grades] would be renamed to). And the tag excerpts/wikis should probably be edited to clarify the distinction as well.

Comment: I have updated the tag descriptions.