# Should the [grades] and [grading] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-cleanup-proposal

We have both [grade](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grade) and [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading), witho 83 and 50 tagged questions respectively. I am afraid I am responsible for this mess because I created [grading](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grading) 2 years ago, when [grades](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grades) already existed.

Could the two be merged?

Answer (score 3):

There is an existing [tag synonym proposal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags/grades/synonyms) for those, with a current score of -1. Users who have an opinion on this are invited to vote on the tag synonym.

There is a discussion about that downvote [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/why-would-a-user-downvote-an-obvious-tag-synonym).

Comment: (Note: It looks like the mentioned synonym proposal no longer exists, now that several years have passed...)